# how to unittest private method in c# with PrivateObject

Tags: c#, unit-testing, private-methods

Im trying to make a simple unit test of a private method and I let VS2010 autogenerate the method stubb and add the missing info: This is the code I have

```
[TestMethod()]
        [DeploymentItem("MyPackage.Language.dll")]
        public void getValidCultureWithValidInputCulture()
        {
            CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE", false);
            PrivateObject param0 = new PrivateObject(culture, new PrivateType(typeof(CultureInfo)));
            GlobalResourceProvider_Accessor target = new GlobalResourceProvider_Accessor(param0);
            CultureInfo expected = new CultureInfo("sv-SE", false); 
            CultureInfo actual = target.getValidCulture(culture);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
        }
```

When I run this I get a exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: 
      The member specified (getValidCulture) could not be found. You might need to regenerate your private accessor,
      or the member may be private and defined on a base class. If the latter is true, you need to pass the type
      that defines the member into PrivateObject's constructor.
```

Does anyone know what i´m doing wrong here? My Objective is to learn how to use the PrivateType and PrivateObject for private methods testing.

EDIT:

Im not not looking to use the PrivateObject.Invoke (it's not refactor friendly).

Comment: You shouldn't unit test private stuff at all, imo.  Your testing should be around the behavior of your public API, not the implementation details of private methods.  Private methods are, if anything, internal helpers in support of some public action.

Comment: One thing we did to test non public methods was to make them protected instead of private. And then have the test class derive out of them so it would have access to those methods. Not the best approach since we had to change the modifier to protected, but it got the job done.

Comment: @Paul I do not agree with you on this, but thats not relevent for this problem.

Comment: @VishalKumar Yes that is usualy what I do as well but then I heard of this fancy stuff and would like to learn how to use it.

Comment: @VishalKumar I don't think `protected` is a good idea, since `protected` members on a non sealed class are part of the public surface area of that class. IMO `internal` together with `InternalsVisibleTo` is a much better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. To correct this I made sure the `Local.testsettings` and `TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings` both had the correct files selected (`Debug`, `Release`, etc) in the "Data and Diagnostics" option.

This is if you have code coverage on, or any of the settings that allow to select the assemblies you will be using. Select the correct set, compile and try the unit test again. Sometimes you need to recreate the accessor. I have a base class as well, but it seems to be working fine with any `Public Static` method.